# Pandas: Take all characters before the first digit appears

Tags: python, pandas

Considering the dataframe below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker': ['EWZ US 05/29/20 P27', 'HSI US 12/30/20 C24800', 'TLT US 06/19/20 C225'],
                   'Market': ['US NYSE', 'US NYSE', 'HK HKSE']})
df
```

I need to create a new column with all the characters that appear before the first digit in `df['Ticker']`. I'm try the following:

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
f = lambda x: len(df['Ticker'].split(numbers)) -1
df['Reduced_Ticker'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

but I receive the following error: `'Series' object has no attribute 'split'`. Can anyone help? Output expected:

```
        Ticker         |  Market | Reduced_Ticker
EWZ US 05/29/20 P27    | US NYSE | EWZ US
HSI US 12/30/20 C24800 | US NYSE | HSI US
TLT US 06/19/20 C225   | HK HKSE | HK HKSE
```

Comment: Did you try `df['Ticker'].str.split(numbers)`? [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Comment: yes. The error: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, assuming what you provided is a full representation of your dataframe, you can do something with `split()`  (on 2nd space) and `join()`:

```
df['Reduced_Ticker'] = df['Ticker'].apply(lambda a :" ".join(a.split(" ", 2)[:2]))

                   Ticker   Market     new Reduced_Ticker
0     EWZ US 05/29/20 P27  US NYSE  EWZ US         EWZ US
1  HSI US 12/30/20 C24800  US NYSE  HSI US         HSI US
2    TLT US 06/19/20 C225  HK HKSE  TLT US         TLT US
```

Comment: this answer is nice but the other one is vectorized, so much faster for large dataset.....

Comment: @adirabargil actually, string operations are barely vectorized.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df['Reduced_Ticker'] = df['Ticker'].str.extract('^(\D+)')
```

Output (extra space at the end):

```
                   Ticker   Market Reduced_Ticker
0     EWZ US 05/29/20 P27  US NYSE        EWZ US 
1  HSI US 12/30/20 C24800  US NYSE        HSI US 
2    TLT US 06/19/20 C225  HK HKSE        TLT US
```

To remove the trailing space, chain with `str.strip()`:

```
df['Ticker'].str.extract('^(\D+)')[0].str.strip()
```

Comment: Very simple. Thanks!

Comment: Rather than an extra call to strip, why not just match a space outside of the capture group?  If it doesn't always appear it can be an optional match.

Comment: @user3483203 that might fail if some ticker is not separated from the digits by a space (which unlikely as depicted in the sample data, but not given).

Comment: Right, which is the point of the optional match `\s?`.

Comment: I tried the optional, didn't work, the space is still captured.